# Performing variance inflation factor with R

Tags: multiple-regression

Am working with R and I want to use the vif function to perform multicollinearity test but then any time I run what I get is "Error:could not find the function "vif"". I need help around this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Which package did you load? None? Not all functions are available directly in R. That´s what the packages are for.

I suggest installing the package **car** and using the function **vif()** therein.

Comment: Alright but then is car installed in R or its package on its own? Please If it has to be installed in R, how do I do it?

Comment: With install.packages ("car", dep=T)  after install load package via library (car) and then see the help file for vif with ?vif  - good luck